# PHP variable to javascript + modal

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, modal-dialog

I want to create modal button for delete a user gets from a foreach in the html body.
The modal opens an iframe with a form. The iframe url seems like

```
<iframe src=<?php echo base_url('index/page/');?> witdth....
```

I want to pass to the iframe src the php variable  contains an userid, for example:

```
<iframe src=<?php echo base_url('/index/page/'+username);?> witdth....
```

First code works fine and it shows the view but no variable passed with the second code.
I use a javascript for open the modal and get the ID variable.
The link:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-detail-id=<?php echo $users->username; ?>>
```

And the js:

```
        <script>
    $(".myModal").on("click", function(e) {
      var username;

          e.preventDefault();

          username = $(this).data("detail-id");


      });
    </script>
```

How to get the detailId to the iframe src to pass the variable to the index/page?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT---
I will post full code, the ovjective is to pass a PHP variable got in a foreach to a modal windows in that calls a iframce to other view to use the variable:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-detail-id=<?php echo $users->username; ?>></a>
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <script>
        $(".myModal").on("click", function(e) {
          var username;

              e.preventDefault();

              username= $(this).data("detail-id");


          });
        </script>

        <center><iframe src=<?php echo base_url('/index/page/'+username);?> width="500" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></center>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: post full js code. where are you generating iframe ? post that code too.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing JS and PHP together:

```
<iframe src=<?php echo base_url('/index/page/'+username);?> width.... ( note the + )

<iframe src=<?php echo base_url('/index/page/'.$username);?> width....  ( append with . operator )
```

In PHP, you append with . operator

Comment: you are correct about the appending syntax but `username` is `js varable` and **NOT** a `PHP variable` as i can see in the code. so `$username is wrong`

Comment: OP is also using a *PHP* variable, if you see `$users->username;`. He can use it there.

Comment: there can be an object of it which generates multiple links on that page. in that case he need to get `CLICKED` link's username or i should say `data-detail-id`

Comment: dude, the script OP is using is for the second modal example, don't be mad at me but `<iframe src=<?php echo base_url('/index/page/'.$users->username);?> width....` will work just fine IMO, no need for any JS there.

Comment: as he has mentioned he is using foreach to generate links say `foreach($result as $user) {?> <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-detail-id=<?php echo $users->username; ?>> <?php } ?>` so the page will have `Many anchors for each user` on `click` of any anchor `data-detail-id` of that anchor will be the username in iframe src (`in js`). in that case `<iframe src=<?php echo base_url('/index/page/'.$users->username);?> width....` i hope I'm not being a nab and you are getting me.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are looking for easy solution to delete smoething (ex. user) you can use something like this in your view:

```
<script>
function doconfirm()
{
    job=confirm("Are you sure, to delete?");
    if(job!=true)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>

<?php foreach ($users as $user_detail): ?>
    <a href="/users/delete/<?=$user_detail['user_id']; ?> onClick="return doconfirm();">Delete user</a><br>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

and from your user model try somethig like:

```
public function delete($user_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    return $query = $this->db->delete('users');     
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's very usefull but i'm interested in use iframe cause I have more functions than delete something but I keep it in mind :)